# org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I have a project that runs fine in eclipse. However, when exporting it to jar (both executable jar and regular jar), I'm getting the above exception when running it. My classpath contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/commons-math3-3.2-javadoc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/commons-math3-3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/Jama-1.0.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/jcommon-1.0.21.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/jfreechart-1.0.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

And as you can see, the third entry is the right lib.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because commons-io is not on the classpath.. I mean eclipse classpath is not your java classpath when you run the jar

Comment: @RC but FileUtils.class is in commons-io-2.4.jar

Comment: @RC I'm not following. Should I export another file that I hadn't to the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the commons-io library to the classpath of the jar. Note that when you create a jar with your code the linked libraries are not included in it and need to be in the classpath of the jar. For example, if commons-io was in the libs folder in Eclipse you'll need to distribute a libs folder containing the required libraries with your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a manifest.mf in the META-INF folder inside the jar?
In the manifest you can set your classpath

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Or you can create a jat with inside all your dependencies, I suggest to use maven with Shade plugin

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html